# I didn't understand the meaning of counterfactual antecedent in this paragraph

Tags: meaning, comprehension

> We often assert counterfactual conditionals, as in ‘If I had gone to the market today, then I would have bought a quart of milk.’ (That I went to the market today – the falsehood in the ‘if’ position of the conditional – is the ‘counterfactual antecedent’.)

(From [this article](https://aeon.co/essays/natural-laws-cant-be-broken-but-can-they-be-defined))

Comment: What don't you understand about it? *counterfactual* means it didn't happen. That means I didn't go to the market, and I didn't buy a quart of milk.

Comment: Welcome! Please edit to show that you've looked up both words in a dictionary, what you found, and what questions you have afterwards.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It is about meaning and also lacks any sign of research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will start with some links to the Lexico dictionary.

[counterfactual](https://www.lexico.com/definition/counterfactual)

[antecedent](https://www.lexico.com/definition/antecedent) see definition 4 Logic

In the example, "If I had gone to the market today", the reader understands that I did **not** go to the market, i.e the "falsehood". This is the counterfactual antecedent being the activity that didn't happen, contained within the "if" statement.

Comment: If we had some bacon, we could have bacon and eggs, if we had some eggs.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Please take a moment, though, to read about [the topics that are covered here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). "Counterfactual" and "antecedent" are certainly not everyday words, but as you show, they're easy to find in dictionaries, and as such this question as it stands is off-topic. Instead of providing an answer, it could be helpful to encourage the user to tell more about their confusion, in case it is actually about more than the meanings of the two words.

Comment: Noted and understood.